# calloc overwrites another variable's memory?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, calloc, data-management

I am writing a program to create a gray scale image (`image`) using calculations on data stored in source array (`hist`). The data stored in source array resets to zero after calling calloc for image.

```
func1(){
    float * hist = (float *) calloc(256, sizeof(float));
    // operation to populate 'hist'
    for...{
       for...{
           hist.....
       }
    }

    hist2img(hist);
    free(hist);
    return 0;
}

hist2img(hist){
    cout << "-> " << hist [4 * 250] << endl;

    unsigned char * image = (unsigned char *) calloc(256 * 256, sizeof(unsigned char));

    cout << "-> " << hist [4 * 250] << endl;

    free(image);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
-> 0.997291
-> 0
```

What happens to the data? All elements in `hist` are 0 after the calloc instruction. I need `image` to be initialized to 0.

```
--(~$)--> gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609

--(~$)--> uname
Linux 4.7.2-040702-generic x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: `hist [4 * 250]` pointer arithmetic going wrong here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You allocate 256 floats:

```
float * hist = (float *) calloc(256, sizeof(float));
```

and you access to the 1000th element, which is UB

```
cout << "-> " << hist [4 * 250] << endl;
```

The calloc call zeroes some memory that you were mistakingly pointing to

To gain access to the 250th float element of `hist`, just

```
cout << "-> " << hist [250] << endl;
```

(since `hist` is a pointer on `float`, the compiler computes addresses by multiplying float size, no need to do that yourself)

If you know the size in advance, it's even better to allocate data statically

declaration:

```
float hist[256]={0};
```

When defining `hist2img`:

```
hist2img(float hist[256]){
```

in that case you get a warning when static index is going out of range (but still crashes/UB if some variable index is going off-bounds: there are no run-time checks)

Comment: You don't need `memset` for zeroing an array – `float hist[256] = {0};` is enough and impossible to get wrong. (`memset(hist, 0, sizeof(hist))` is safer than the explicit size calculation, but not quite as safe as initialisation.)